# TeXlipse doesn't generate any pdf file

Tags: pdf, errors, compiling, mac, texlipse

I've just installed TeXlipse using the simple installing option (Install new softwares -> http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) on my Mac OS.

I create a new LaTeX project, select output format = pdf, build command = pdflatex. However, no pdf file was generated. I tried to turn off automatically build and then clicked build but still nothing happened.

In console, it's written:

```
/usr/bin/open -a /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app "/Users/myusername/Documents/workspace/TexLipse"
```

Can someone please explain me how to build pdf file with TeXlipse in Mac OS X?

Comment: How did you install your TeX distribution? (Not TeXlipse itself, but your actual TeX distribution?  You should be using [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/).

Comment: i think i have a similar issue.
i've set up all the right paths, but the building process halts at 4% and the console output is: running: /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex pdflatex> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
pdflatex> restricted \write18 enabled. running pdflatex from the console works and compiles perfectly any hints?

Comment: @simon This is not an answer to the question. If the accepted answer does not solve your problem, consider asking a fresh question specific to your problem.

Comment: @simon: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect something went wrong with the configuration of the builder settings. I had a similar problem which required me to reconfigure that part of the installation process. When I clicked Build nothing happened, but after fixing this it works.

See the screenshot below and the following url [Texclipse installation and configuration - Part 2](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/configuration.html)

[image]

Insert `/usr/texbin` where it asks for the "Bin directory of TeX distribution". This will access the files at `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin` if you've got the 2011 version of MacTeX installed.

Comment: I think you're right, Mcgafter. However, I'm not sure how to setup these paths in Mac OS. The only directory I found for texlipse is /Users/usrname/Documents/software/eclipse/plugins/net.sourceforge.texlipse_1.4.2 but when I hit apply button, nothing is set. I tried to setup the path to each program, e.g. pdflatex, but I only found **texi2pdf** in /usr/bin and setting pdflatex to that one doesn't help. Any thought on that?

Comment: If MacTeX has been installed, `/usr/texbin` should be used instead of the path to the executables. It's probably better to leave, say, `latex` in the first line and filling the box "Bin directory" with `/usr/texbin`. In theory, at least. (I don't have Eclipse to make a try.)

Comment: Thanks, egreg. But there is no /usr/texbin as well as anything start with "tex"

Comment: Mcgafter, I couldn't find /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin directory.

Comment: @chepukha: Use egreg's path which he mentioned. `/usr/texbin`. That will automatically redirect to the proper installed path. If you've got 2010's MacTeX version it might be `/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin`. The `/usr` directory is hidden by default. To view it's contents select `Go->Go to folder` from a `Finder` window and type in /usr/ in the box. You could also use a tool such as TinkerTool or OnyX to display hidden files and folders if you really want to.

Comment: I actually did try both of those options that you mentioned. I also use 'ls -a /usr(/local) ' to find anything related to 'tex' but didn't find anything there. I will try to reinstall the plugin again.

Comment: OK, I understand why now thanks to Alan Munn. I didn't understand any Tex distribution.

Comment: Any solution for the same issue on windows?